# Visual Studio Express 2013: How to create project with existing C++ source files ?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-express

There has been a lot of discussion about this topic but still no concrete answer about it or atleast I can not find it. I am unable to find the option **File->New->Project from existing files**
I have already the source files and to avail the advantage of some tools in visual studio express I installed the trial version 2013 and even after playing with it a little bit and looking for it on internet I did not find this option. 
Is there any possible way to create project with existing source files like this in 2013 version ? 
or should I install some older version ?

Suggestions/comments/solutions .. Please

Comment: I think you can always create empty project and add existing files manually? But i guess that doesn't satisfy your needs.

Comment: The last version that had that option was VS2008.  I've only ever used that option once on VS6.  It was the same as creating an empty project and adding the files manually.

Comment: Related, from 2011: [Import Existing C++ Source Code into Visual Studio](//stackoverflow.com/q/4853550)

Comment: And, from 2008: [How do I add an existing directory tree to a project in Visual Studio?](//stackoverflow.com/q/392473)

Answer (score 3):

You could try creating a blank project and then importing the files into it. Not sure if the version you're using is able to do that. Otherwise, create a new project and new source files and copy/paste the code (it's not a great solution).

Answer (score 1):

In Visual Studio Express 2013 I found I was able to export an existing project as a template then build a new project off of that template.

File -> Export Template
then 
File -> New Project and the saved Template was available to choose from.

Answer (score 0):

According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/754c3hy7.aspx "This option ( File->New->Project from existing files) is not available in Visual Studio Express editions..." so the short answer would be "no."
@JBentley - the OP asked if he could perform the task "like this", where "this" means "using File->New->Project from existing files".

Comment: Just because that particular method is unavailable doesn't mean the OP can't achieve his objective a different way.

Comment: This also isn't available anymore in Visual Studio Professional. Bad answer for anybody these days. http://i.imgur.com/7zXU6El.png